# Samba Permission denied

Tags: permissions, rhel, samba

I need to deploy Samba Sharing between Linux Host (Samba Server) and Linux (Client) and Windows (Client) . Now this folder on Server will share documents between Linux and Windows Client machines. On Samba Server i made two test users lets call them venice and john. Now on Samba Server I set the file context for samba and enabled RO and RW booleans and set the permissions for john and venice

```
> getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
> # file: samba/docs/
> # owner: venice
> # group: venice user::rwx user:venice:rwx user:john:rwx group::r-x mask::rwx other::r-x default:user::rwx default:user:venice:rwx
> default:user:john:rwx default:group::r-x default:mask::rwx
> default:other::r-x
```

and in samba configuration file i did following configuration

```
[smbdocs]
        comment = Documents share
        path = /samba/docs
        browseable = yes
        read only = yes
        write list = venice john
        guest ok = no
        printable = no
        hosts allow = 10.8.8.51
```

While mounting on samba using

```
mount.cifs //10.8.8.50/smbdocs -o username=venice,password=pass /samba/docs/
```

im not able to create files using venice and john users, even though it is allowed from system level permission and Samba level.

Now if i mount using the uid and gid of venice

```
mount.cifs //10.8.8.50/smbdocs -o username=venice,password=pass,uid=1001,gid=1001 /samba/docs/
```

im able to create the file using venice user but john still not able to create the files or edit the files

Any advice

Host OS version RHEL 7.4

Comment: Maybe you can mount it twice, e.g. for `venice` at `/home/venice/samba/docs` and for `john` at `/home/john/samba/docs` using the respective `uid` and `gid`.

Answer (score 1):

RHEL 7 has SELinux enabled by default, and it *will* restrict Samba's access to the filesystem. When you create your own Samba share in a custom path like `/samba/docs`, you must apply suitable SELinux labeling to that path.

If you need the directories accessible by Samba and other services, you should use SELinux context type label `public_content_rw_t` and set the `smbd_anon_write` SELinux boolean to allow Samba write access to files and directories in `public_content_rw_t` contexts with full control of file ownerships:

```
setsebool -P smbd_anon_write=1
semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_rw_t "/samba/docs(/.*)?"
restorecon -Rv /samba/docs
```

If you don't plan on accessing `/samba/docs` through any other service (like `httpd` or `ftpd`), you can use `samba_share_t` context instead, and then you don't need the boolean setting:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t "/samba/docs(/.*)?"
restorecon -Rv /samba/docs
```

The `semanage fcontext -a...` command will add the regular expression that defines the new labeling persistently into SELinux configuration, and `restorecon` will apply the new labeling to the actual filesystem. You could also use `chcon` to change SELinux context labels, but then your changes would be lost whenever `restorecon` was executed (e.g. after restoring a backup). Storing the labeling information into SELinux configuration first ensures it can be restored even if your backup methods are not specifically SELinux aware - as long as the SELinux configuration under `/etc` is also backed up.

Comment: yes, File context are already set .

drwxrwxr-x+ root root system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0 /samba/docs/